# GameBoy Advance SP won't load anymore

Tags: technical-issues, game-boy-advance

I recently got me two of my favourite games again on GameBoy Advance SP.

I played just a few hours with one device and then went to bed. On the next day, the battery was empty - ok. But trying to charge it again failed.

When I plug in the power source to my GBASP, the "loading LED" lights orange (intended) for only 1-2 seconds and then turns off (not intended). The loading process is then aborted.

Luckily I got another GBASP for me, which loads with the same power source perfectly, but I want to know if I can easily repair this damage.

**Is this a known problem and how can I repair it?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the two games? Love the GBA.

Comment: Well it's Dragon Warrior Monsters I and II for the GB. :D Just playing on an SP for the backlight. :)

Comment: @Trollwut Hehehe I have Pokemon Yellow on mime and I got a GBASP for the backlight, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can search ebay or amazon for just a battery replacement, or find an aftermarket external battery. Thing is its 2015 and parts have most likely been discontinued for the sp. Start searching thrift stores, flea markets and pawn shops for sps. I found one today for 5 bucks. Try seeing if it still operates while connected to the charger.